# Oracle Apex - Moving a table with Blob column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I've been tasked with copying a table from Workspace 1 into Workspace 2.
The table contains files stored in a Blob column (pdfs and such).
How can I copy this table and all Blob contents from Workspace 1 into Workspace 2?

Thanks

Comment: Are the workspaces in the same APEX installation, or in separate database instances?

Comment: Workspace is a specific APEX concept, while a table resides in a schema in the Oracle database. Do you really have to move that table? If so, the easiest thing would be creata table dest_schema.dest_table as select * from source_schema.source_table. Then create also the indexes and triggers for that table if so required. Then drop the old table. But, if that is a large table, taking many GB, why not simply grant select, insert, update, delete to another oracle user on the already existing table and not copy it any longer. One more thing: is the table partitioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- this is Oracle
- table belongs to **user** (not Apex workspace)
- when you install Apex in a database, that's (just) another schema with its own objects
- in order to be able to create Apex applications, admin creates a **workspace** and developer who is allowed to work in that workspace
- as we develop applications whose source is an Oracle database (i.e. data stored in tables in certain user's schema), admin also has to designate database schema to Apex workspace
- at the end, you - as developer in that workspace - can access that table

Saying that you want to "move table from one workspace to another", well, that doesn't make much sense. Admin should designate schema that contains table you've mentioned to another workspace. Nothing should actually be *moved* or *copied* anywhere.

If you don't want to do that and really need to move table(s) around, use utilities designed for that purpose: **Data Pump** export and import and

- export table from user who owns that table
- import it to another user, the one whose schema is designated to workspace 2